# inform about vs inform of

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrase-usage

What is the difference between "inform of" and "inform about"?

Can you give some example sentences which clearly shows the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think *inform of* **merely** talks about the 'information of something' and *that's it!*

Say...

> I'll have to ***inform her of*** Joe's kidnapping

So, here, we are informing her that Joe is kidnapped. And that is all!

On the other hand,

> I'll have to ***inform her about*** Joe's kidnapping

Means, not only will she be informed that Joe is kidnapped but **also** the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more about the usage, there are slightly different nuances. Use **of** when the object is specified:

> Your father should be informed **of your** conduct.

Use **about** when the object is not specified:

> Your father should be informed **about any** nonsense you said.